# Android studio issues, missing platforms, design editor

Tags: android

I'm new to AS and having a fair few problems. I've tried a few things in other people's threads to no avail.

It says I'm missing platforms but as you can see in the images I've got all the version 28 stuff installed. However, it asks for v 26.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm pulling my hair out, I just want it working, so I can start my course.

I'm using V 3.0.1, and don't want to upgrade as I'm using free wifi that isn't the best.

Any help would be awesome, TIA.
Scott

Answer (score 0):

You specified to use SDK v26. Set `compileSdkVersion 28`and `targetSdkVersion 28` in your build.grandle so it will not ask for SDK v 26 . 
Read this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion

This is a programming question so please use stackoverflow next time.

Comment: I didn't specify anything as I wouldn't know how. How do I fix it? I tried changing it to 28 before following other peoples threads but to no avail.

Comment: if you changed these parameters, the selected sdk version is 28. Remember to sync the grandle build like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932793/syncing-android-studio-project-with-gradle-files

Comment: Does this also need changing ?
`    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'  `

Comment: Maybe, but if there is no error Message when you sync the grandle it schould be ok. If you didn't edit these, maybe you could try to create a new project and specify the target version in the creation wizzard.

Comment: Well I've changed those 2 entries to 28 in a new project, with min sdk as  21. And it doesn't change anything. Do I just go File  >  Synchronise if I make changes to the gradle file?

Also, do I need the platform for minimum sdk or just max?

Comment: Thanks for your help @trietend, I finally figured it out. I added in buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"

And I also change the appcompat v to 27.1.1.

Thanks again, it's on to my first hello world app :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't specify anything as I wouldn't know how. How do I fix it? I tried changing it to 28 before following other peoples threads but to no avail.

Edit to add;
I've changed both parameters to 28, also minsdk was set to 28, should that be lower?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scott.justworkdamnit"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

p.s. I'll remeber to use stackoverflow next time, thanks ;)